# Collections within Documents for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

For an application I manage the data is currently within Google's NoSQL Firestore database. We're working on switching the data over to a self hosted server with Mongo for the database.

Firestore supports collections inside of documents to further categorize your data. Is this possible with Mongo?

For example: Collection(Clothes) -> Document(Tops) -> Collection(T-Shirts) -> Document(T-Shirt 1)

Comment: Documents can contain subdocuments, or arrays of subdocuments, but not collections, which are the top level of the data.  I certainly wouldn't recommend stuffing everything into a small number of documents though, so you're probably going to have to rethink your model a bit for mongodb.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!